# Failed Validation with MongoDB Schema

Tags: mongodb

Using MongoDB v3.6.2, I am attempting to design a schema validation (which will ultimately hold more values than detailed below). My current layout has the following structure:

**Schema**

```
db.createCollection("Products", {
    validator: {
        $jsonSchema: {
            bsonType: "object",
            required: ["ProductId",
                       "ProductName",
                       "Bonus.PremiumRate",
                       "Bonus.InterestRate",
                       "SurrChargeRates.First",
                       "SurrChargeRates.Second",
                       "SurrChargeRates.Third"],
            properties: {
                "ProductId": {
                    bsonType: "int",
                    description: "Must be a numerical representation of ID"
                },
                "ProductName": {
                    bsonType: "string",
                    description: "Must be a string representation of Product Name"
                },
                "Bonus.PremiumRate": {
                    bsonType: "decimal",
                    description: "Must be a decimal representation of Premium Rate Bonus"
                },
                "Bonus.InterestRate": {
                    bsonType: "decimal",
                    description: "Must be a decimal representation of Interest Rate Bonus"
                },
                "SurrChargeRates.First": {
                    bsonType: "decimal",
                    description: "Must be a decimal representation of First Surrender Charge Rate"
                },
                "SurrChargeRates.Second": {
                    bsonType: "decimal",
                    description: "Must be a decimal representation of Second Surrender Charge Rate"
                },
                "SurrChargeRates.Third": {
                    bsonType: "decimal",
                    description: "Must be a decimal representation of Third Surrender Charge Rate"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    validationLevel: "strict",
    validationAction: "error"
});
```

This is accepted by MongoDB and creates the collection and validation successfully. However, when I attempt to insert a document I am met with the error code 121, `Document failed validation`.

The `insert` I am trying currently is the following:

**Insert**

```
db.Products.insert({
    "ProductId": NumberInt(1), 
    "ProductName": "Product Name",
    "Bonus.PremiumRate": NumberDecimal("0.3"),
    "Bonus.InterestRate": NumberDecimal("0.5"),
    "SurrChargeRates.First": NumberDecimal("0.1"),
    "SurrChargeRates.Second": NumberDecimal("0.1"),
    "SurrChargeRates.Third": NumberDecimal("0.1")
});
```

I have also tried this `insert` negating all `NumberInt` and `NumberDecimal` tags, with no change. Additionally, setting `validationAction: "warn"` allows for the document to be inserted but isn't the desired functionality. Likewise with removing all items from the `required` object.

What is currently the issue with this schema design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following command:

```
db.Products.insert({
    "ProductId": NumberInt(1), 
    "ProductName": "Product Name",
    "Bonus" : {
        "PremiumRate": NumberDecimal("0.3"),
        "InterestRate": NumberDecimal("0.5")
    },
    "SurrChargeRates":{
        "First": NumberDecimal("0.1"),
        "Second": NumberDecimal("0.1"),
        "Third": NumberDecimal("0.1")
    }
});
```

The reason for the failure is dot notation. `Subdocuments` should be inserted as above.

Comment: Well dang! That worked perfectly. I had assumed that dot notation would work due to it being used in the construction of the schema. Thank you!